# Ant to delete subdirectories and files in subdirectories but not any file from the directory itself

Tags: ant, build

My requirement is to delete all subdirectories from a specified directory, but NOT delete files in the specified directory.

I have fussed around with fileset and dirset and I could not get a single collection to do the job.  What works is this:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true" >
    <fileset dir="release/reports" >
        <exclude name="*.*" />
    </fileset>
    <dirset dir="release/reports" includes="**/*" />
</delete>
```

Isn't there a way to do this with one collection (either fileset or dirset)?

Answer (score 1):

It should work like that :

```
 <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
  <fileset dir="C:/yourdir" includes="**/*" excludes="*.*"/>
 </delete>
```